# cognito in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, aws

I have read all the documents dev doc of Magento from adobe. I understand that we can describe the dependencies in composer.json for each module. but I want to use Cognito as well with the existing 2FA of Magento. I really not interested to take a route of pipedream or socket io for this. rather I would like to take the path for Cognito using AWS sdk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html
or amplify framework
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js#configure-your-application
any idea how to make this work?

php 7.4
ubuntu 20.4 ec2
mysql rds 8.x
es 7.6.0 currently (within the same host)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been researching the same thing but what I came across as the easiest option is to get an OAuth module from this place.

https://plugins.miniorange.com/magento-oauth-single-sign-sso

Comment: looks like product or plugin recommendations and it is mostly against the forum rules. mini orange (i am not interested) I will mostly consider anything else. for self-hosted stuff I won't pay a single penny to others specifically in subscriptions pay mode. not interested with oauth at all.

Comment: then write an oAuth module yourself for magento and link it to cognito using the API keys and oAuth capabilities from Cognito. You wouldnt need to use the SDK. Im just saying, I came across an existing solution. Plus they have a free version with enough capabilities.

Comment: their free plan is not capable of assigning your app roles. Cognito itself is an authentication service. why do we need outh for this? please stop promoting products. product-based questions and solutions are a violation of sof se policy.